# Unexplainable non-existing page requested for months

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt, 404, page, botattack

While I am quite familiar with bots requesting well-know pages as used for WordPress and phpMyAdmin on any site the can reach, I'm now dealing with a bot requested a page I really can't explain.

For months now, a page `/featured/like?id=XXX` (with `XXX` being a 3-digit integer) is being requested 10+ times a day for the last six months, from multiple IP addresses from countries like France, Germany and Ukraine (site is hosted and targeted at The Netherlands).

This page doesn't exist and it's not indexed by any search engine.

I'm almost sure this is just another bot trying to find a page used by some framework, but it's been going on for months now, so I just want to make sure.

Does anyone know why this page keeps being requested?

Answer (score 2):

Hm...

The quick way to prevent robots visiting your site is put these two lines into the `/robots.txt` file on your server:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Try to put this for one day, and see what happens. This only helps with well-behaved robots.

But, if you like to disallow that page specifically,

```
Disallow: /featured/
```

Do that, and see what happens.

Comment: The problem is that the OP is calling these accesses "bots" where they are very likely compromised computers landscaping systems for vulnerabilities and not bots at all. It is all script-kiddie stuff and should not be called a bot. It confuses the issue. It is a hacker that will not obey any robots.txt rule.

Comment: Being a bot or not, this solution is worth a try.
I'll add the line to ythe robots.txt and will check it after the weekend.
Thanks, Josip!